# Why do we say $f(x) = x^2/x$ is undefined at 0 when it equals $f(x) = x$

Tags: limits, functions, continuity

Apologies if this has been asked somewhere else. Why do we say $f(x) = \frac{x^2}{x}$ is undefined at 0 when it literally equals $f(x) = x$. Am I making a mistake in saying that $\frac{x^2}{x} = x$?

Indeed why does any function with a removable discontinuity, such as $\frac{x-2}{x^2-4}$ (which can be rewritten as $\frac{1}{x+2}$) actually "have" the discontinuity if we can always rewrite it in some way which makes the limit easy to evaluate?

Comment: There is a difference between $x$ and ${x^2 \over x}$. The latter is only defined for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: $f(x)=\frac{a(x)}{b(x)}\,$ is not defined where $b(x)=0$.

Comment: What is fot you $\frac{0^2}{0}$

Comment: @JMoravitz yes, that is perfect. Thank you very much.